# Filling missing data for two columns in pandas dataframe using non missing data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a pandas dataframe with 3 columns.

```
data = data[['id','foo','bar']]
```

for about 1% of the dataset both foo and bar are missing, but not id. I'm looking to impute with random pairs of non-null `foo` and `bar`. Assume id is never null and either foo and bar are both null or both non-null.

Comment: Random pairs? So anything given to fillna can work?

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html ?

Comment: @Wen, I'm looking for a random imputation strategy

Comment: @Evert it has to be from the non-null data

Comment: fillna will put in any value where data is null/None/NaN/missing.

Comment: @Evert something like data.fillna(random.choice(...)) would fill all NAs with the same random pair. I'm looking for a different random pair for each missing pair.

Comment: You could probably mask the null values, create two series/2D array of random values of the same length, and replace the the masked values. Looks like that is roughly what Michele87's answer is about.

Comment: What type are the foo and bar columns?

Comment: @Evert floating point

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to do something like this?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
index = range(10)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,2), index=index, columns=['foo','bar'])
df['foo'].iloc[0:4] = np.nan

invalid = df['foo'].isnull()
nInvalid = df[invalid].shape[0]
valids = df['foo'][-invalid]
nValid = valids.shape[0]
randomInst = np.random.randint(0,nValid,nInvalid)
df['foo'].loc[invalid] = valids.iloc[randomInst].as_matrix()
```

Edit to apply to bar as well:

```
df['bar'].loc[invalid] = df['bar'][-invalid].iloc[randomInst].as_matrix()
```

Comment: close! I'm looking to fill foo and bar at the same time, but also with the non-null data in the df

Comment: I believe that does that, did you mean you want to allow for parts from bar to replace NaNs in foo as well as parts from foo?

Comment: See my last line I've added. Will this work for your case? This assumes bar is always and only invalid when foo is invalid

Comment: nevermind; yours work much better than trying to impute both at once. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Can this help you?

```
 import pandas as pd
 data = pd.DataFrame(data)
 invalid_data = data[(data['foo'].isnull()) & (data['bar'].isnull())]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that when the 'foo' value is missing, the 'bar' value is also missing (as per your question), and that the column types are floating point:

```
mask = df['foo'].isnull()
df.loc[mask,['foo', 'bar']] = np.random.random((np.sum(mask), 2))
```

---

If you want to use valid values from the actual dataframe itself (as they better represent the value range of your data), you could use the following instead:

```
df.loc[mask,['foo', 'bar']] = df[['foo', 'bar']][~mask].sample(np.sum(mask)).values
```

(possible with `replace=True` as argument to the `sample` method; ditto for `np.random.random`, of course.)

Comment: the second part was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: problem - the second part doesn't actually fill in the df.

Comment: @StevenNguyen Yep, sorry 'bout that. I've fixed (cheated) that by use the `.values` attribute: that avoids Pandas keeping track of the indices, which don't match properly (the sample is created from indices with non-NaNs in their row, while they need to be assigned to indices with NaNs in their rows: that doesn't match properly).